# List files with Unicode names in python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode

I am new to python. I am using it to batch process a number of text files with Unicode characters in both filenames and content. I have declared the encoding in the beginning. I am able to process the Unicode content but when I try to list files on windows, this is what I get.

```
26-??????-P.txt
```

The actual name of the file is

```
26-देहजरी-P.txt
```

This is the script I am using

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from os import listdir

allfiles = [f for f in listdir('./')]
    for f in allfiles:
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
            print f;
```

I want to selectively open and process the text files and output new files with similar names as the input files (so that they can be matched later).

Please guide on how this can be accomplished. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just... use Python 3: it has built-in Unicode support _and_ it’s the future of the language, so you’ll be getting all the new features with it, while Python 2’s development will soon be suspended.

Comment: Thanks @ForceBru for your suggestion.

Comment: This is looking more like a cosmetic display problem if you are able to open and process the files

Comment: you mean non-ASCII names? because all the letters like a-z 0-9 are also Unicode

Comment: @tripleee, no, using bytes (2.x. `str`) paths is discouraged in Windows because it's limited to the system ANSI codepage and otherwise uses best-fit conversions. Using bytes paths in Windows was formerly deprecated in Python 3 because of this. Finally in Python 3.6 the Windows file-system encoding was changed to UTF-8. Internally it decodes bytes paths to UTF-16LE and uses the Windows wide-character API.

Comment: @eryksun Definitely not something I recommend but the question seems unclear on what exactly the problem is. Again, if they are able to open and read the files, not being able to display the file name is a distant secondary concern IMHO.

Comment: @tripleee, these "?" characters are a common result of best-fit conversion in the ANSI API. In some specific cases there may be an actual best-fit mapping, such as "∞" -> "8", but usually it ends up using the default "?" character. There is no codepage for Devanagari text; I think systems in India use the Western Europe codepage, 1252, as the system ANSI codepage, in which case I'd expect all question marks. If it were correct as ANSI and decoded by the console using its legacy codepage (OEM by default), then I'd expect mojibake instead of question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to set Unicode on your path.

**Ex:**

```
import os
for i in os.listdir(u"C:\\Your\\Path\\Folder"):   #I have used 'u' before the path
    print i
```

**Output:**

```
26-देहजरी-P.txt
```

Comment: Python 2 doesn't correctly support raw `unicode` literals, so backslash has to be doubled as in this answer. You can use forward slashes with OS functions, or forward slashes plus `os.path.normpath` if backslashes are required, such as with some shell commands.